# How can I integrate authentication with Docusaurus in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, docusaurus

I am building a documentation website using  Docusaurus 2.0 and I would like to add authentication to restrict access to certain pages. I have looked at the  Docusaurus 2.0 documentation but could not find any information on how to achieve this. is there any reference

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. **Thank you in advance**.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this https://medium.com/@thomasdevshare/docusaurus-authentication-with-firebase-c824da24bc51 , he explained clearly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).